# Unable to fetch data within a certain radius of the user

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am having a hard time fetching events based on the users preferences.

Below is the query that works perfect ::

```
const get_straight_events_query = `
SELECT 
    e.id AS event_id,
    u.gender,
    u.age ,
    u.height_feet,
    u.height_inches,
    u.has_kids,
    es.interested_sex,
    es.interested_has_kids,
    es.intersted_min_height_feet,
    es.intersted_min_height_inches,
    es.min_age,
    es.max_age,
    u.gender,
    e.latitude,
    e.longitude
FROM events e
JOIN event_search_settings es ON e.created_by = es.created_by
JOIN users u ON e.created_by = u.id
WHERE 
    e.created_by != $1 AND
    u.gender = $2 AND
    u.age >= $3 AND
    u.age <= $4 AND
    u.height_feet >= $5 AND
    u.height_inches >= $6 AND
    u.has_kids = $7 AND
    es.interested_sex = $8 AND
    es.max_age >= $9 AND
    es.min_age <= $9 AND
    es.intersted_min_height_feet <= $10 AND
    es.intersted_min_height_inches <= $11 AND
    es.interested_has_kids = $12 
 
;

`;
```

I need to add the condition of only fetching events that are within a certain distance.

this is what the event table looks like::

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    active BOOLEAN,
    created_by VARCHAR(255),
    updated_by VARCHAR(255),
    created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    location VARCHAR(255),
    description VARCHAR(255),
    state VARCHAR(255),
    time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    latitude FLOAT,
    longitude FLOAT
);
```

This is the class that allows me to fetch data from postgres::

```
class EventService {
    async get_events(data) {
        console.log("[EventService]  get_events " ,data);
        if (data.user_interested_sex == BOTH) {
          //
        } else {
            return await pool.query(get_straight_events_query, [
                data.user_id,
                data.user_interested_sex,
                data.user_interested_min_age,
                data.user_interested_max_age,
                data.user_intersted_min_height_feet,
                data.user_intersted_min_height_inches,
                data.user_interested_has_kids,
            
                data.user_gender,
                data.user_age,
                data.user_height_feet,
                data.user_height_inches,
                data.user_has_kids,    
            ]);
        }
    }



}
```

this is what i am printing as an output so i know i am passing in the values::

```
  [
  {
    event_id: 'f2c5e6e1-5a73-46d7-ab32-82c0c3cecfcf',
    gender: 'female',
    age: 31,
    height_feet: 5,
    height_inches: 10,
    has_kids: false,
    interested_sex: 'male',
    interested_has_kids: false,
    intersted_min_height_feet: 4,
    intersted_min_height_inches: 0,
    min_age: 18,
    max_age: 90,
    latitude: 37.785834,
    longitude: -122.406417
  }
]
```

this is what i see in the databse::

```
juan=# SELECT * FROM events;
                  id                  | active |              created_by              |              updated_by              |       created_on        |       updated_on        | location | description | state | creator_gender | creator_interested_sex |        time         | latitude  |  longitude  
--------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------------+-------+----------------+------------------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------
 8447ccb1-9c3a-4643-9f38-bf8b3fa62137 | t      | a2c88f6e-fdb8-4720-9a99-ee5fb2fc5b2f | a2c88f6e-fdb8-4720-9a99-ee5fb2fc5b2f | 2023-12-24 11:43:40.867 | 2023-12-24 11:43:40.867 | China    | Make-female | new   | male           | female                 | 2023-12-24 06:43:29 | 37.785834 | -122.406417
 f2c5e6e1-5a73-46d7-ab32-82c0c3cecfcf | t      | 729fdf98-95bd-43ba-8531-d32ec749078b | 729fdf98-95bd-43ba-8531-d32ec749078b | 2023-12-24 11:44:17.148 | 2023-12-24 11:44:17.148 | Canada   | Female-male | new   | female         | male                   | 2023-12-24 06:44:04 | 37.785834 | -122.406417
(2 rows)

juan=#
```

I tried adding this from a stackoverflow post but no luck::

```
  AND (
        6371 * acos(
            cos(radians($13)) * cos(radians(e.latitude)) * cos(radians(e.longitude) - radians($14)) +
            sin(radians($13)) * sin(radians(e.latitude))
        )
    ) * 0.621371
```

Comment: "*I tried adding this from a stackoverflow post but no luck:*" -> Mind sharing a link to said post so we can judge what it says and whether you applied the recommendation correctly?

Comment: "No luck" is if anything even worse than "didn't work".  Please provide an actual description of what went wrong.

Comment: I figure it out, i was passing in null values, thank u for the help!!